# Property … does not exist on type ‘{ [key: string]: AbstractControl; }’

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

When production compiling a form in Ionic2 (based on Angular2) I keep getting the error:

```
Property email does not exist on type ‘{ [key: string]: AbstractControl; }
```

I've tried various ways to create my form like:

**method 1**

```
   this.recoverPasswordForm = new FormGroup({
        email: new FormControl('me@me.com', Validators.minLength(2)),
    });
```

**method 2**

```
    let control = fb.control('', Validators.required);

    this.recoverPasswordForm = fb.group({
        'email': control
    });
```

**method 3**

```
    this.recoverPasswordForm = new FormGroup({
        email: new FormControl('me@me.com', Validators.minLength(2)),
    });
```

All keep giving the same error.

`ionic serve` doesn't raise any errors, but `ionic run android` does. According to the developers running on a device is a stricter compiler. However I can't figure out what the correct form definition should be.

According to the [Angular2 documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/FormGroup-class.html) these method 1 should be correct.

Does anyone know what could cause this compilation error?

Comment: Try `{['email']: new FormControl...}`. Or create the form and set the property using `form['email']`.

Comment: For sec, I checked 1st way & seems to working, check [plunkr here](http://plnkr.co/edit/RHHjM1nyP0BbOamrdxl0?p=preview) (so I didn't checked other)

Comment: The Plunkr works however there is a stricter compilation ionic does when it runs on a device. The compile error is then only triggered which makes it hard to debug. Thanks for looking into this issue anyway!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turned out the problem is caused when `this.recoverPasswordForm` is defined as:

`recoverPasswordForm: FormGroup`

instead when I use

`recoverPasswordForm = null` there is no problem

**Update**

After issuing a bug report it turned out my template was the problem: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/12181#issuecomment-252471832

I was using `recoverPasswordForm.controls.email` instead of `recoverPasswordForm.get('email')` in my template.

Answer (score 0):

Until Ionic fixes this in a later release, here is a workaround to disable prod mode (Strict compilation for mobile builds) that I have found to work for the time being.

Replace your `main.prod.ts` contents with the contents found in `main.dev.ts`, will look something like this:

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app.module';

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

Edit: I found out you can get good debug information from using a build target: `ionic run android --device`, should spit out proper warnings/errors again. In my case I thought the accessors it was complaining about were in my .ts, but they were actually in my html and were using a `.` accessor, not `[]`.

Comment: Thanks for you answer! According to the Ionic team this is a code problem and not a problem with their production build script. Therefore I should change my code to compile for strict.